# Multiply row by column with awk

Tags: awk

Good afternoon,
I'm trying to do the following multiplication with awk:

```
0    1       2       3
2 A21*A12 A21*A13 A21*A14
5 A31*A12 A31*A13 A31*A14
4 A41*A12 A41*A13 A41*A14
```

Input:

```
0 1 2 3
2
1
3
```

Expected output:

```
0 1 2 3
2 2 4 6
1 1 2 3
3 3 6 9
```

Is it possible to do this using awk?

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '
    NR == 1 {n = split($0, a)}
    NR > 1  {for (i=2; i<=n; i++) $i = a[i] * $1}
    {print}
' input
```

```
0 1 2 3
2 2 4 6
1 1 2 3
3 3 6 9
```